Bt table filter extension:- how to filter dropdown value filter out?
How to filter dropdown value based on new data on first filter.
Like only $0 needned in second dropdown value 
Simple table value filter then based on filtered result value dropdown value come to UI.
Thanks
I see the github code for bt table filter extension but i didn't identify any idea

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

This option actually used to exist, up until version 1.19.1. https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table/issues/6740 explains.
However, you can still use 1.19.1 and get the desired result.
This is a working example, as linked in the issue above: https://live.bootstrap-table.com/code/francogiacobbi/14995
If you click Libraries at the top, you will see that CDN Version is 1.19.1.
Here is a minimal example showing the same: https://live.bootstrap-table.com/code/nickjrotundo/17513

what about new  version 1.22.5?

It is not supported in the new version. The discussion is the first link in my answer. It may be supported again in the future, I'm not sure.
